# Is it more efficient to pass a string array or 6 strings to a constructor?

Tags: c#, .net

I am passing string arrays to the constructor of my objects, because they are related, I do not however need to manipulate the collection in any way (sort, or any other array operation) I just piece the strings in the array into different variables in the receiving class. I simple find it convenient passing the array rather than 6 string. Will this result to any performance issue?

Comment: It's difficult to know if it will cause performance issues without knowing how frequently the method is called etc. etc. To me, this smells of micro-optimization. Do what is most obviously correct (i.e. don't violate the principles of least astonishment). When you come back to the code in a years time, will it still make sense? In particular, passing arrays when you expect a fixed number of parameters, leaving you to write code like `var something = someArray[0]` is leaving yourself open to bugs down the road.

Comment: @spender I think your comment should be an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is performance really a concern?  You should read [Eric Lippert's performance rant](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) for a little perspective.

What's more important is the *design*.  You want to avoid methods with too many parameters, so this argues for passing the array if your values are truly a collection of similarly-typed, independent values, or make a class with properties if these values logically belong together in some "form" (I'm trying to avoid the word "class" here, but that really describes it best).

Comment: Thanks for the link, I found it very useful.

Answer (score 4):

With an array of only six objects there are no performance implications to worry about.

Code readability and maintainability should be your primary concern: a constructor with six clearly named parameters is a lot more readable than a constructor that takes an array of strings.

Consider these two examples:

```
Employee1(string first, string last, string position) {
    ...
}

Employee2(string[] args) {
    ...
}
```

The caller of `Employee1` will get an IDE prompt which explains the purpose of each parameter, while the caller of `Employee2` would need to know which argument goes in which position in the array.

An alternative to pass named parameters to the constructor is available only to the users of `Employee1`:

```
var manager = new Employee1(position:"manager", first:"Vincent", last:"Nwonah");
```

In addition, the implementation of `Employee2` needs to worry about callers passing an array with fewer than three elements or an array with more than three elements.

In short, `Employee1` provides a much more readable and maintainable alternative.

Comment: I get your point but in my situation now I think passing arrays is more readable as the values I am passing never change. I authenticate a user, and read details about that user from a database into say 'userDetailsArray'. Every other class the user uses throughout his session needs to know his privilege, username, year, etc. I have taken care to make a nice comment where I wrote the details into array as to which details goes into which array index. If there is no performance issue I think passing array is more readable in this particular situation.